# DeviceWatcher.Added method creating compilation issues

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

I am in an initial stage for developing a BLE library using DLL(Universal Windows) using VS2019.
Below showing the code snippet.

```cpp
void Device::StartDeviceScan()
{
    // Additional properties we would like about the device.
    auto requestedProperties = single_threaded_vector<hstring>(
        { L"System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress",
          L"System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected", 
          L"System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.IsConnectable" });
    // list Bluetooth LE devices
    hstring aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices =
        L"(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\")";
    
    m_DeviceWatcher = Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(
        aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices,
        requestedProperties,
        DeviceInformationKind::AssociationEndpoint);
    
    // Register event handlers before starting the watcher.
    m_DeviceWatcherAddedRevoker = m_DeviceWatcher.Added(
        winrt::auto_revoke,
        &Device::DeviceWatcher_Added);
```

While building the project i am getting following issues,

```
1>E:\Piu_projects_test\SensorDll\SensorDll\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(5170): error C2516: 'H': is not a legal base class
1>E:\Piu_projects_test\SensorDll\SensorDll\Generated Files\winrt\Windows.Foundation.h(888): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::implements_delegate<winrt::Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher,winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation>,H>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            H=void (__cdecl infinitysensormodule::Device::* )(winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher,winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation)
1>        ]
1>E:\Piu_projects_test\SensorDll\SensorDll\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(5219): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::delegate<T,H>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>
```

Could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: What's the signature of `Device::DeviceWatcher_Added`?

Comment: @IInspectable
void DeviceWatcher_Added(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher sender, Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation deviceInfo);

Comment: That `__cdecl` looks odd, but maybe that's just a result of the template matching gone wrong. At any rate, you'll need to pass the class instance into the typed event handler's c'tor (`m_DeviceWatcher.Added(winrt::auto_revoke, { get_weak(), &Device::DeviceWatcher_Added });`). I tend to use weak references so as to not get any dependency cycles. You can see a fully working example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cppwinrt).

Comment: i have already gone through the example earlier. But i am constructing a simple dll with c++/winrt extention. I am not using any IDL files here. Consuming the library via dllexport method. Below is the Class header.

Comment: As I said, you'll need to pass the class instance along with the member function pointer. Otherwise the compiler has no way of knowing on which class instance to call the member function. This is unrelated to how you expose your API.

Comment: namespace sample
{
    class Device
    {
    public:
        Device();
        ~Device();
        void StartDeviceScan();

        void DeviceWatcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation deviceInfo);

        DeviceWatcher m_DeviceWatcher{ nullptr };
        DeviceWatcher::Added_revoker m_DeviceWatcherAddedRevoker;
    };
}

Comment: i agree with this.
But i do have issue while using get_weak().
    
deviceWatcherAddedToken = m_DeviceWatcher.Added({ get_weak(), &Device::DeviceWatcher_Added });    Here i am using a normal class

Comment: If you aren't implementing a type that derives from `IInspectable`, pass `this` instead.